# Required attribute in select doesnt work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to put required attribute to select. I tried many ways and it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <select class="form-control" name="Category" required="required">
        <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="2">Library Staff</option>
            <option value="3">Non-Teaching Staff</option>
            <option value="4">System Admin</option>
            <option value="5">Teaching Staff</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code, including the form tag. There's not apparent reason why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [boostrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-examples):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/master/dist/validator.min.js"></script>

<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Category</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <select class="form-control" name="Category" required>
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="2">Library Staff</option>
                <option value="3">Non-Teaching Staff</option>
                <option value="4">System Admin</option>
                <option value="5">Teaching Staff</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

try;

```
<select class="form-control" name="Category" required>
```